# psycopg2: inexplicable 'DataError: incorrect binary data format'

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using a `COPY ... WITH BINARY` query.

The tables I'm copying, only contain integers and only go into tables containing integers. But on one of the dozens of `COPY` queries, I get the error:

```
psycopg2.DataError: incorrect binary data format
CONTEXT:  COPY daemon_link_43_47_4_7813, line 1, column 4_id
```

As I said, all values are integers. And when I dump the file not using `WITH BINARY` I can see the particular file contains a single line containing two numbers (so two columns): 12 and 35. How on earth could this cause an 'incorrect binary data' error? Could there be any other reason besides the data format causing this error? I've checked all column types, and everything is definitely `int`.

Comment: `From the feel of it ...` is not an objective standard. I would just stick with a regular `COPY` and get the job done. Per docs [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html): "Also, the binary format is very data type specific; for example it will not work to output binary data from a smallint column and read it into an integer column, even though that would work fine in text format." So this is finicky format. If you want an answer you will need to provide the table definition, the entire `COPY` statement and a sample of the data. Add as update to question.

Comment: Thanks for explaining to me that my gut feel is not an objective standard. And copy-pasting the docs, also very handy. I'll take expanding my answer into consideration.

Comment: You asked ' How on earth could this cause an 'incorrect binary data' error?' The quote gave you the answer. In Python `type(12) int`. From here [psycopg2 type adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types): Python --> Postgres `int smallint`. Betting your table columns are set as `integer`. The documentation is a good place to start which is why I point at it.